# Python colorbar: how to stop its repeating in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a for-loop to generate a set of images:

```
for p in range(0,153):
im=plt.imshow(M[p,0:28,:].T,extent=[0,time.max(),depth.max(),0],aspect='auto')
plt.tight_layout()
cbar=plt.colorbar(im,orientation='vertical')
cbar.set_label('Vz[mm]')
plt.title('Rohdaten '+str(p)+'. Umlauf D874 Ch5')
plt.xlabel('Messzeit[s]')
plt.ylabel('Messtiefe[mm]')
savefig(os.path.join('/Users/gaoyingqiang/Desktop/1-153Umlauf',str(p)+'.png'))
```

But it turns the colorbar in the images was looping like:
[image: weird isn't it?]

I cannot understand why the colorbar was repeating itself.

Comment: looks like at least one instruction should be inside the for loop (use `pass` otherwise)

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: You have nothing inside your for loop. Since python don't use braces, you need at least one instruction inside. Use `pass` if you need to leave the loop empty

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki funny but i think that's just an indentation error from copying the code to SO

Comment: Python uses indentation for delimitation of blocks. Therefore posting code with correct indentation is **essential**, otherwise we have to figure out. The code posted is syntactically incorrect since it contains an empty loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interprete the incomplete code correctly, you want to save different figures, each with a colorbar.

1. You could actually create different figures and not operate on the same figure over and over again by closing the old figure, `plt.close("all")`.
2. You could clear the old figure using `plt.clf()`, thereby operating on the same but emptied figure.

Example:

```
for p in range(0,153):

    im=plt.imshow(M[p,0:28,:].T,extent=[0,time.max(),depth.max(),0],aspect='auto')
    plt.tight_layout()
    cbar=plt.colorbar(im,orientation='vertical')
    cbar.set_label('Vz[mm]')
    plt.title('Rohdaten '+str(p)+'. Umlauf D874 Ch5')
    plt.xlabel('Messzeit[s]')
    plt.ylabel('Messtiefe[mm]')
    savefig(os.path.join('/Users/gaoyingqiang/Desktop/1-153Umlauf',str(p)+'.png'))
    plt.close("all")
```

Comment: yes. I added plt.figure(p) and it was all right. Many thanks!

Comment: I would strongly recommend closing the figure as soon as it's not needed any more, otherwise you'll end up with 153 open figures in the memory, which may cause trouble.

Comment: In any case if this answers the question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. If you like it, you may also upvote it (which is true for just any question or answer you find here and which helped you in one way or the other).